# extend child div to right edge of entire page

Tags: html, css

---

### UPDATE

EDIT: Sorry guys, I'm afraid that I defined the problem wrong, my bad.. I need this to have a image carousel (YELLOW) break out of the main text division (RED); only on the right side. So what would work as well for me is something like this:

Fiddle: [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/by61f2Ln/5/)

HTML:

```
<div class="red">
This would contain the main text
</div>
<div class="yellow">
this div's left border should align with the red divs
<br/>
<br/>
this would be the image carousel
</div>
<div class="red">
this would also contain the main text
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.red{
position:relative;
height:100px;
width:500px;
margin:0 auto;
background-color:#ff0000;
}
.yellow{
position:relative;
height:200px;
width:100%; /* idk how to solve this */
background-color:#ffff00;
right:0px;
left:100px; /*how to align this left border to the other red divs? */
}
```

Now the main problem is to align the left border of "yellow" with the left border of the text divs (red).

I hope I'm being clear enough. Thanks for all the help so far :) Sorry for making a mess out of this thread.

---

### ORIGINAL POST

I try to let a child div connect to the righter outermost edge of the page. This div (yellow) is placed within a parent div (red) that fills only the center area of the page. Is this possible somehow?

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="red">
    <div class="yellow">
        this div should extent to outermost right of entire page
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.red {
    position:relative;
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#ff0000;
}
.yellow {
    position:absolute;
    height:200px;
    width:100%; /* idk how to solve this */
    background-color:#ffff00;
    top:100px;
    right:0px; /* this applies to div.red but should apply to the entire page somehow */
}
```

Here's the fiddle:
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/by61f2Ln/1/)

Kind regards,
Steven

EDIT: here's the photoshopped result:[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLP5Y.jpg)

Comment: As you've already used `position` for *yellow* `<div>` then why're you using `width:100%;` if you want to stuck to righter most part ? alter *width* to 50 OR 60 it will put it to righter most.

Comment: When I do that it puts the yellow div on the right bound of the red div, not on the entire page. Furthermore, the left borders of both divs should be kept aligned.

Comment: if you want to cover whole page with *red* div then change its `width` to 100% and keep *yellow* one to 50-60.

Comment: No sorry that is not what I want. Can you take a look at the image in the bottom of my original post?

Comment: Is this purely decorative or will the yellow div have content that extends ouside the red area?

Comment: @Steven I'm on SO App otherwise I'll definitely write Fiddle for you. Meanwhile for achieving that do this: a. create a container with `width` and `height` 100% and make it `position: relative`. b. then make your *red* div with same properties and just make it `absolute` and add `left:0` `right:0` `top: 0`. c. Now *yellow* one, just reduce its `width` to 60 or 70 keeping rest of the properties same. Try this it will do the trick for you.

Comment: one more thing to add *red* will be child of *container* and so as *yellow* don't make *yellow* inside of *red*.

Comment: That would result in this, right? [link](https://jsfiddle.net/by61f2Ln/4/) How do I keep the left borders of both divs aligned? Sorry if I got it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need [this](https://jsfiddle.net/dttr1nv5/)?

```
.red {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

.yellow {
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #ffff00;
    top: 100px;
    left: auto;
    right: 0px; 
}
```

**UPD:** I'm not sure that you can find only-CSS solution. So, you can add [some jQuery](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epYrdN) or [pure JS](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbOxVj).

Comment: Almost!

The left borders of both divs need to kept aligned, only the right border of the divs should mismatch. Is that possible?

Comment: Alright, my bad. Your solution solves the problem I defined for 100%. I'm however afraid that I defined the problem wrong. Sorry for being a dick. Problem is that the red div continues "behind" the yellow div. Now considering that my red div will be used for "text" part of it won't be visilble. I will update my original post and try to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Use below css. let me know is it the one you are looking.

```
.red{
position:relative;
height:500px;
width:500px;
margin:0 auto;
background-color:#ff0000;
```

}

`.yellow{
    position:absolute;
    height:200px;
    width:400px; /* idk how to solve this */
    background-color:#ffff00;
    top:100px;
    right:0px;
    left:0px;
 /* this applies to div.red but should apply to the entire page somehow */
    margin:auto;
}`

Comment: I used your CSS, but that makes the yellow div centered within the red. I've update the original post with a photoshopped image of the desired result.

Comment: i was unable to see photo-shopped image.. where it is??

Comment: Sorry, just uploaded it!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and found this unanswered question — then my maths brain kicked in.

Use `vw` to work out the dynamic right margin. The `calc` works out the total of the margins either side of the red div, halves that and makes it negative.

To get the width, it adds the above calculation (except without the negative) to the width of its container.

```
.red{
    position:relative;
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#ff0000;
}
.yellow{
    position:absolute;
    height:200px;
    width: calc(100% + ((100vw - 100%) * 0.5));
    background-color:#ffff00;
    top:100px;
    margin-right: calc((100vw - 100%) * -0.5);
}
```